# Passing data types from Java to C (or vice versa) using JNI

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

Using JNI can we pass custom data types from Java to C (or vice versa)? I see a mapping of primitive datatypes to types in C however not too sure if we can send across our own data types (e.g. Send across or return an Employee object or something!).

Comment: You can. If you want to make Java/C translation easier, check out [Swig](http://www.swig.org/), which allows you to translate [between Java and C/C++ structures](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Java.html) in a straightforward fashion..

Comment: You can use [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/) to easily pass structures around. JNA allows you to write your binding completely in Java code. :-)

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/jni#2-using-objects-and-calling-java-methods-from-native-code

Answer (score 75):

If you're going to be doing this with a lot of objects, something like Swig would be best. You could use jobject type to pass around custom objects. The syntax isn't nice, perhaps there is a better way to write this.

Example Employee object:

```
public class Employee {
    private int age;

    public Employee(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
}
```

Call this code from some client:

```
public class Client {
    public Client() {
        Employee emp = new Employee(32);

        System.out.println("Pass employee to C and get age back: "+getAgeC(emp));

        Employee emp2 = createWithAge(23);

        System.out.println("Get employee object from C: "+emp2.getAge());
    }

    public native int getAgeC(Employee emp);
    public native Employee createWithAge(int age);
}
```

You could have JNI functions like this for passing an employee object from Java to C, as a jobject method argument:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_Client_getAgeC(JNIEnv *env, jobject callingObject, jobject employeeObject) {
    jclass employeeClass = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, employeeObject);
    jmethodID midGetAge = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, employeeClass, "getAge", "()I");
    int age =  (*env)->CallIntMethod(env, employeeObject, midGetAge);
    return age;
}
```

Passing an employee object back from C to Java as a jobject, you could use:

```
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_Client_createWithAge(JNIEnv *env, jobject callingObject, jint age) {
    jclass employeeClass = (*env)->FindClass(env,"LEmployee;");
    jmethodID midConstructor = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, employeeClass, "<init>", "(I)V");
    jobject employeeObject = (*env)->NewObject(env, employeeClass, midConstructor, age);
    return employeeObject;
}
```

Comment: I have problems with "LEmployee;" part I tried with "com.pak1.Employee" and with "Lcom.pak.Employee;" but no result, any ideas ?

Comment: @Lukap: if your class is com.pak.Employee then the signature of the class will be "Lcom/pak/Employee;"

Comment: @mafioso you can create an object of class "Ljava/lang/string;". Commenting for completeness, doubt you actually still need this...

Comment: The `jclass proc_jclass = env->FindClass(“Lcom/my/class/JavaClass”);` method needs to be called at the FIRST LINE of your `JNI` function or else you may experience `ClassNotFoundExceptions`. Also, this did not work for me with the semi-colon in the class path. Once I removed the semi-colon from the classpath string, it worked. This is a Great answer!

Comment: swig is too complex and hard to use.