# Connect C++ class with Kotlin/Java class through JNI

Tags: java, c++, kotlin, java-native-interface

Is it possible to pass same class object from C++ to Java/Kotlin class object and vice versa through JNI.
For example lets say I have this class in C++

```cpp
class A {
  ...
}
class B {
  A a;
}
```

and in Kotlin

```kotlin
class A {
 ...
}

class B {
 var a : A = A() // or smh
}
```

and in JNI

```cpp
JNI_METHOD(jobject kotlin_object_B) {
  B b;
  env->FillKotlinObject(kotlin_object_B, b); // or smh
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's allowed by JNI. I don't know about Kotlin but with Java is definitely possible

Comment: Can you provide an example or smh, even if its only for Java! thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504334/passing-data-types-from-java-to-c-or-vice-versa-using-jni